# KnpMenuBundle, extend Builder by ContainerAware and Controller

Tags: symfony, knpmenubundle

I m using KNPMenuBuilder to create a menu. I would like to add query in my Builder.php but I need to extend Builder class by Controller. By default it`s extends by "ContainerAware".

I would like to ask how to extends Builder class by two elements- "ContainerAware" and "Controller"?
Or how can I create a DQL query without extending of Controller?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `Controller` class is just a "tool" to easily use controllers (some people even say it's a bad thing to use, as it's somewhat advocating a service locator pattern).

You shouldn't extend `Controller` in any class other than a controller.

To get access to doctrine (like the `Controller#getDoctrine()` method), you should request for the `doctrine` service. Then you just have the same as you have when using the `getDoctrine()` method.

Since the builder extends `ContainerAware`, you have access to a `$container` property and you can `get()` the `doctrine` service from it:

```
$doctrine = $this->container->get('doctrine');
$em = $doctrine->getManager();

$query = $em->createQuery(...);
```